How can i keep/merge the faces of the bool object that has intersected trough the original mesh?
Maya has a boolean operation called difference A-B.i want to recreate this in blender basically what i want to happen in blender is like the pic bellow. One thought that came to mind is using a mesh boolean Union and then somehow delete the bool faces that are outside the mesh but i lack the experience to do so
so far i have only been able to do this. but what i want is to carve out the building as if it was solid and not just a plane

this is what the result i am looking for


Are your meshes manifold ? It is a requirement for boolean operations, otherwise you can get unexpected behaviors. Blender's difference should be similar to Maya's difference.

You want the plane (not a volume, but a surface) with a hole "cut out" by the sphere (a manifold volume) ?

not cut out but more like dug in like in picture 2, i could use boolean union on the object and then delete the part that i dont want but that would  take much more time if i have to repeat it on multiple objects

Geometry nodes for a plane
Here, extrude the plane to a size that is enough, transform it into a big prism and it's done:

The original object and plane:

Result 1 (without "invert plane")

Result 2 (With "invert plane")

Simple alternative: the boolean modifier
Use the "boolean" modifier. Union, intersection or difference.

After you "apply" the modifier, the result is this:

And there are material options:


thanks for the answer but i'd like to do it on a plane. basically digging out the plane without having to add any thickness to it

Updated answer. @PhilipBretschneider

that worked! Although the mesh i wanted to do it on is a bit too complex so i'll have to do some more cleanup work on the mesh itself thanks for the help

(Using Blender 4.2.4)

Figure 1: (top) Face Orientation - (left) Original objects to intersect, (right) Result from differences and union ; (bottom) GeometryNodes graph.
(Blender 4.2.4+)
Analysis
Let $S$ be a manifold object (a Sphere for the demonstration) and $P$ be a non manifold object (a Plane for the demonstration). The sought non manifold object is the union of two objects, $S-P$ and $P-S$ where $\bullet-\bullet$ is the boolean Difference operation. Besides, only the skin of $S$ is kept. From the documentation of the Mesh Boolean node, $M_1 - M_2$ is keeping everything of $M_1$ that is outside of $M_2$. It is to notice from Fig.(1)
that the "inside" of $P$ is the half 3D space below. From the faces orientation displayed Fig.(1):

$S-P$ is the skin of $S$ that is inside $P$.
$P-S$ is the part of $P$ that is outside $S$.

GeometryNodes modifier
The GeometryNodes modifier is attached to the default Cube for the demonstration to offset the result, using two Object Info nodes to recover geometries. It could be attached to any of the two objects, using a single Object Info node to recover the other geometry.
Dark pink nodes: Computation of $S-P$
1. The faces orientation of $P$ is flipped before the Mesh Boolean node such that the skin of $S$ to keep is outside of flipped $P$.
2. The original faces of $S$ are tagged with a True boolean value which is captured as an attribute in Face domain under the label "Kept". For new faces generated by the Mesh Boolean node, this attribute is initialized at False. Consequently, those are conveniently removed with a Delete Geometry node.
3. Eventually, the faces orientation of the kept part of $S$ is flipped to be consistent with the orientation of $P$.
Dark blue nodes: Computation of $P-S$
4. Because the part of $P$ to keep is already outside of $S$, no face orientation manipulation is required before the Mesh Boolean node.
Dark green nodes: Computation of $(S-P)+(P-S)$
5. The meshes union is achieved with a sequence of Join Geometry and Merge by Distance nodes.
